# $K/F$ is Galois and $\alpha \in K$ with $T(x) = \alpha x$ on $F$. Then $\text{Tr}(T) = \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(K/F)} \sigma(\alpha)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose that $K/F$ is a Galois extension and that $\alpha \in K$. Then consider the linear transformation $T : K \rightarrow K$ given by $x \mapsto \alpha x$.

Then we want to show two things:

$\text{tr}(T) = \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(K/F)} \sigma(\alpha)$ and

$\text{det}(T) = \prod_{\sigma \in Gal(K/F)} \sigma(\alpha)$

I know that the trace is the sum of eigenvalues and the determinant the product, so it seems the natural thing to show is that the eigenvalues are permuted by the Galois group, but I am confused here. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with $x$, then it seems to me that: $T(x) = \lambda x = \alpha x$ and thus $\lambda = \alpha$ and so $\alpha$ is the only eigenvalue. I think I'm conflating vector space scalar multiplication and field regular multiplication, but I'm not sure how to untangle the two either.

Would appreciate some clarity.

Comment: This is available in any introduction text in Algebraic Number Theory, see e.g. Corollary 2.20 in [Milne's ANT](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf)

Comment: I think that in this case, talking about eigenvalues leads one astray. Don’t you have any other definition of norm and trace?